# Use a shell script to obtain a params for every wildcard

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake, wildcard-expansion

I have an R script in my workflow that requires the number of entries on several csv files (`a.csv`, `b.csv`, `c.csv`; formatted with headers) as a value. Since they all have a string `something` in every line, I thought I could write the rule as follows:

```
configfile: config.yaml
WILDCARD = config['wildcard']
TEMP_DIR = "~/temp"

rule all:
    input:
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{{WILDCARD}}/output.txt"

rule combine_geno_pheno_data_sibs:
    input:
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/file.txt",
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{{WILDCARD}}/another_file.txt",
        f"config['file']",
    output:
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{{WILDCARD}}/output.txt"
    params:
        n_lines = shell(
            "grep -c something ../resources/{{WILDCARD}}.csv | xargs"
        )
    script:
        "scripts/use_lines.R"
```

`config.yaml` contains

```
wildcard:
   - a
   - b
   - c
```

and `n_lines` is called in R as `snakemake@params$n_lines`.
The way the expansion is interpreted in `shell()`, though, is as `grep -c something ../resources/a b c.csv`, how do I get it to interpret the wildcards as e.g. `grep -c something ../resources/a.csv` and return the value to `n_lines` correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

And I didn't really follow what your pipeline does but perhaps this is what you want?

```
configfile: config.yaml
WILDCARD = ['a', 'b', 'c']
TEMP_DIR = "~/temp"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{WILDCARD}/output.txt", TEMP_DIR=TEMP_DIR, WILDCARD=WILDCARD),

rule combine_geno_pheno_data_sibs:
    input:
        somefile= "{TEMP_DIR}/file.txt",
        anotherfile= "{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{WILDCARD}/another_file.txt",
        csv= lambda wc:  '../resources/%s.csv' % wc.WILDCARD,
    output:
        "{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{WILDCARD}/output.txt"
    script:
        "scripts/use_lines.R"
```

I would get the `n_lines` counts inside the R script with standard R code. E.g.

```
csv <- read.table(snakemake@input$csv, ...)
n_lines <- nrow(csv[csv$somecol == 'something', ])
```

I don't have much sympathy for `script` directive because it can see everything in the snakemake workflow so it is not clear what it takes in input. I prefer to write a standalone R script that you execute via `shell` directive. But this is unrelated to your question...

(Note that in your `rule all` you miss the `input` directive but I guess this is a typo).

Answer (score 0):

Given the `config.yaml`, the `WILDCARD` contains a list of string values:

```py
WILDCARD = config['wildcard']
# WILDCARD = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

By applying f-string formatting to rule `all` input, you are really requesting the following file:

```py
rule all:
   input: f"{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{{WILDCARD}}/output.txt"
#        "~/temp/folder/{WILDCARD}/output.txt"
```

It's not clear if you are then requesting specific files from command line or if the code in the question is slightly inconsistent, but to fix your rule, consider defining a utility function that counts number of lines containing "something":

```py
def _count_lines(f):
    path = f"../resources/{f}.csv"
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(path) if "something" in line)
    return num_lines
```

Then the rule `combine_geno_pheno_data_sibs` will look like:

```py
rule combine_geno_pheno_data_sibs:
    input:
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/file.txt",
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{{WILDCARD}}/another_file.txt",
        f"config['file']",
    output:
        f"{TEMP_DIR}/folder/{{WILDCARD}}/output.txt"
    params:
        n_lines = lambda wildcards: _count_lines(wildcards.WILDCARD)
    script:
        "scripts/use_lines.R"
```

Comment: The first two bits of the questions are as intended, as I need different outputs for different values of both `WILDCARD` and, consequently, `n_lines`. What is the inconsistency that you noticed?

Comment: Also I don't think your function would count lines in the `.csv` file as is. Maybe calling it as  `lambda wildcards : _count_lines(f"../resources/{wildcards.WILDCARD}.csv")`?

Comment: I am still having issues with this answer, as it doesn't recognise `wildcards`

Comment: Hmmm, what's the error you are receiving?

Comment: `Snakemake InputFunctionException. AttributeError: 'wildcards' object has no attribute 'WILDCARD'`

Comment: This error suggests that there is an inconsistency between the code shared in the question and the code you are executing (specifically in naming of wildcards).